# Is there a problem with using modules under gfortran4.9.2

Tags: gfortran

I have a problem with gfortran 4.9.2

I don't have this problem with gfortran 8.2

I don't have this problem under ifort 17.0.6

Unfortunately, I absolutely have to make my work work in gfortran 4.9.2.

I get the following error message :

```
 mpif90 -O0 -g -Wall -fbacktrace -finit-local-zero -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fbounds-check -cpp -fcheck='all' -c main.f  
 gfortran: internal compiler error: Segmentation error (program f951)
 Please submit a full bug report,
 with preprocessed source if appropriate.
 See <file:////usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
 Makefile:160: recipe for target "main.o' failed
 make: ***[main.o] Error 4
```

In particular the use of the modules lead me to the problem:
My failure is absolutely inexplicable. 
I managed to get around it by doing the following:

This first code doesn't work

```
 MODULE MOD_1
 USE MOD_2

 CONTAINS
 SUBROUTINE SUB_1
 END SUBROUTINE SUB_1

 SUBROUTINE SUB_2
 END SUBROUTINE SUB_2
 END MODULE MOD_1
```

This seconde code works fine

```
 MODULE MOD_1
 CONTAINS

 SUBROUTINE SUB_1
 USE MOD_2
 END SUBROUTINE SUB_1

 SUBROUTINE SUB_2
 USE MOD_2
 END SUBROUTINE SUB_2

 END MODULE MOD_1
```

I simply moved the USE MOD_2 inside the two subroutines

For me it really doesn't make sense. I still have many similar mistakes.
Could someone tell me where to find a description of this problem? 
If I knew him more precisely, I might avoid falling back into it!

I hope to have a link to the problem description and possibly the version of the gfortran patch

Sincerely

Comment: *My failure is absolutely inexplicable* Surely it's entirely explicable as an internal compiler error ?  To which you have found a workaround.  Did you check the fortran bug list ?  Beyond that, for anything like real help, I think you'll have to post a [mcve] exhibiting the problem.

Comment: Internal compiler error is a bug in the compiler. It is not supposed to make sense, the compiler has a problem and it was fixed in one of the later versions. If you need to use the old version, you must find a workaround. It is necessary too isolate the problem first. Te probem should be presentin the GCC bugzillla database.